# Local version of Website running on Virtual Window Machine

Tags: internet-explorer, networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am new to the networking side of things.

I have my local copy of my website running at `localhost:8000` but I would like to test on IE 7,8,9 using a virtual machine.

I have virtual box and virtual machines set up on another mac mini in my house (different machine than where my local copy is..desktop computer).

What steps do I need to take to get the browser on my macmini, on the VM, to show the copy of the website I have running at localhost:8000 on my desktop computer?

**Edit**
Using mac version 10.7.4

Comment: You need to edit your Apache config to allow local addresses to access it, then disable firewall on server side and then use your IP (example 192.168.1.100:8000) to access the web page

Comment: There is also most likely a special reserved IP address in the virtual machine that points to the localhost of your desktop vs the localhost of the VM. You could also always manually edit the hosts files and make up some domain name.

Comment: I don't understand should this have been on serverfault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This will only work if both computers are connected to the same LAN*

Get the Private IP Address of your host computer (see [instructions](http://www.ehow.com/how_2068589_check-macs-ip-addresscheck-macs-ip-address.html))

On the virtual machine(s), type the same URL except replace *localhost* with the Private IP Address of your host computer.

Example: If the host computer's Private IP Address = 10.0.1.1, then the URL to use on the VMs would be *http://10.0.1.1:8000*

Comment: Got it working thanks everyone, learned just a bit more today!